# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)$, when $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ is given.

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> Let $f'(x)=\dfrac{-f(x)}{\sqrt{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}}$ & $g'(x)=1-\dfrac{g(x)}{\sqrt{f^2(x)+g^2(x)}}, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, g(0)=0, f(0)=10$
>
> and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$$, then value of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)=?$$

I don't understand how to use above data to find the answer, l'hospital can't be used. I tried finding relation between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, I got $(f'(x))^2+(1-g'(x))^2=1$. But this don't seem to be useful. How to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the sum of square $f^2+g^2$ plays a major role, it is worth-while looking at it more closely. We have $$\tag1(f^2+g^2)'=2ff'+2gg'=2g-\frac{2f^2+2g^2}{\sqrt{f^2+g^2}}=2\left(g-\sqrt{g^2+f^2}\right)$$
hence
$$ \tag2(f^2+g^2)''=2\left(g'-\frac{2\left(g-\sqrt{g^2+f^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{g^2+f^2}}\right)=2\left(g'+1-\frac g{\sqrt{f^2+g^2}}\right)=4g'.$$
Then from $(1)$
$$ 2\left(g-\sqrt{g^2+f^2}\right)=4g+const$$
so
$$g+\sqrt{g^2+f^2} $$
is constant - and equals $10$ at $x=0$. This must also hold in the limit and we conclude $g\to 5$.

Comment: Wow! How did you think that?